# Background Running Python Script keeps stopping

Tags: python, sleep, background-process

I made a .pyw python script that I want to have running in the background of my computer.
Right now I have it set to launch by putting it in the Startup folder of my Windows 7 computer, which should trigger it to launch whenever it starts up.

The problem is that the script seems to stop running at some point for some reason.  I think it simply stops when my computer goes to sleep and doesn't start running again afterwards.

Is there a "more correct" way to have a background task running that wouldn't have it die every time the computer goes to sleep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there really is need for a continuously running background process, you should look into making a service.

[pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/) helps in creating NT services with python

If you're into .NET, you can try also [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/), but I don't know whether that is more easy.

Comment: Any information on how to do that would be useful, or any references to where to refer to.